# Java-based workflow solutions

Tags: java, workflow

We currently use a sequential workflow to process documents. We have a total of 10 distinct workflow steps. We have re-analyzed the workflow and realized that we could restructure the workflow to process in parallel a number of the workflow steps. Basically we are able to process steps 1,2,3,4 in parallel, wait until steps 1-4 are completed and then process step 5, then process steps 6,7,8,9 in parallel wait until steps 6-9 are completed and then finally process step 10. If we were able to implement this new workflow we could boost our processing throughput dramatically.

My question is: What java-based open-source workflow projects would you recommend? Do they typically support what I outlined above?

**Thanks for all the replies. After taking a quick look at the the websites you all have listed I think I have more than enough to chew on for a while.**

Comment: When you say workflow to process documents.  Could you be more specific on what type of project you are looking at?

Comment: Won't a simple thread do? How about Messaging Service? suggestions/comments?

Comment: Elite Gentleman - I don't think a simple thread class or a simple implementation of a Messaging Service will provide the functionality I am looking for. Notice in my description above that before step 5 can be processed steps 1-4 must be processed first and simlarly for steps 6-9 and step 10. I would guess that an infrastructure that can handle these constraints must be pretty complex. :)

Comment: jzd - The workflow we currently use is pretty simple - document is inserted at step 1 the output of step 1 is handed to step 2, the output of step 2 is handed to step 3, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used [jBPM](http://www.jboss.org/jbpm), and it's pretty nice. It has the parallel processing (forking) and waiting for tasks to be done (joining) the workflow.

The latest version supports a standard notation for business processes - [BPMN](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Business_Process_Modeling_Notation) 2.0

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that some of the jBPM developers have left and started http://activiti.org/

Comment: Yes, I heard that. But I haven't used it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a commercial one called Appian in case you are interested in.

http://www.appian.com/

Comment: this doesn't look like an open-source website 1?

Comment: It's a commercial BPM tool @SyntaxT3rr0r

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [YAWL](http://www.yawlfoundation.org/).

Comment: this doesn't seem quite active. The latest news are from 10/14/2009

Comment: The final release 2.1 is from 2010/07/30 and the sourceforge project seems active to me; http://sourceforge.net/projects/yawl/develop

Answer (score 1):

Spring batch is really nice

http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/

You can define the jobs right in XML.  Has a fairly steep learning curve though, may be too much for a single process if you don't plan to do any more batch processing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you check out [Bonita Open Solution](http://www.bonitasoft.com/). It can do the parallel processing you describe, the provided IDE/Studio is pretty good and the out-of-the-box portal functionality is nice.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on Appian BPM and jBPM. Both are good tools to choose. For complex requirements, Appian BPM should be a really nice option.